# File truncated to 0 bytes during power failure

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, geany

Power went down while editing a file with Geany and the file got truncated to 0 bytes ...  Is it possible to recover the file ?

Comment: What file system is the file on? Did you run `fsck`? Did the file contain anything at a previous point?

Comment: @DavidFoerster the file was on a ext4 file s/m (it was on the root partition)

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally editors rename the file to a backup, usually with a '#' or '~' in the name, and then save the new file.  In your case, the power failed before the new file was written, so just look for the backup.

Comment: Geany does not automatically create backup files (AFAIK) ... and it was not a new file ... i was editing a file which was already on the disk

Comment: @dhaneshsr, yes, and normally editors save the new version to a new file, then replace the original with it, and move the original to a backup.  If there's no backup, then it's gone.